# Convention for global parameter in python module

Tags: python, module, global-variables

I have a module with several plotting functions and I want to have two color themes, one with light color and the other with dark color.

I say I have two methods:

```
def plot_function_1(color_dark='#212121'):
    ...

def plot_function_2(color_dark='#212121'):
    ...
```

That feels kind of redundant. What is the most pythonic way to deal with this? Would I define a variable in the module `COLOR_DARK = '#212121'` and then call:

```
def plot_function_1(color_dark=COLOR_DARK):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `dict` of colors and pass the one required.

```
color_dict = {'COLOR_DARK': '#212121', 'COLOR_LIGHT': '#121212'}

def plot_function_1(color):
    print(color)


plot_function_1(color_dict['COLOR_DARK'])
```

OUTPUT:

```
#212121
```

Another approach (using enum):

```
from enum import Enum

class Color(Enum):
    DARK_COLOR = 200
    LIGHT_COLOR = 400
    DARKER_COLOR = 500
    LIGHTER_COLOR = 222

    print(Color.DARK_COLOR.name)
    print(Color.DARK_COLOR.value)
```

OUTPUT:

```
DARK_COLOR
200
```

Similarly:

```
def plot_function_1(color):
    print(color)


plot_function_1(Color.DARK_COLOR.name)    # or use .value if required
```

Comment: after some time `dict` may be replaced with class (like enum) or module

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Sweet, I'll add that as well.

Comment: btw accessing enum element by attribute (`Color.DARK_COLOR`) is more convenient than by item

Comment: Nice! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your idea is on point. "Convention" is to pull up your values to variable.

If this is module-level variable, you can indicate this by naming it in upper case, pep-8 calls this [constants](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants)